# Backbone.js with $.getScript Extending Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, getscript

I have created a new backbone.js widget model which I hope to extend:

```
        var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({
            constructor: function() {
              console.log('Widget constructor called.');
            }
        });
```

Depending on the page a user views a number of widgets will be loaded via Ajax, so for each widget I will do something like this:

```
        $.getScript('widgets/widget1', function(xhr){
            var widget1 = new pieChartWidget();
            widget1.render();
            widget1.update();
        });
```

Contents of "widgets/widget1":

```
$(function() {

    var pieChartWidget = Widget.extend({
            render: function(json) {
              console.log('Widget render called.'); 
            },
            update: function(json) {
              console.log('Widget update called.'); 
            }
    });

});
```

In my Firebug console I get "pieChartWidget is not defined". I know the Javascript is being loaded successfully, I just cannot extend the "Widget" model from it.

Comment: BTW, there is important stuff happening in the Backbone.Model constructor, and you probably don't want to override it. Use `initialize` instead. Also, the pattern you're suggesting here with getScript is a horrible idea.

Comment: What would you suggest be better than getScript? I'd prefer to load the JS for each widget instance, and have them extend a common Widget model.

Comment: It is much simpler and more maintainable to have all your code in one place (ie a Backbone view) and just exchange data with the server as JSON. Debugging script responses is almost impossible. See?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget is defined within a function. So all variable declared there are only visible withing then functions scope.

```
$(function() {

  var pieChartWidget;

  // pieChartWidget is only visible here!

});

// pieChartWidget not visible here!
```

To have access to the widget from outside of the function you have to assign it to a global variable (eg. your applications namespace). You could also use window (not the preferred way).

Your code should work unchanged if you assign your widget to window like so:

```
$(function() {

  window.pieChartWidget = Widget.extend({
        render: function(json) {
          console.log('Widget render called.'); 
        },
        update: function(json) {
          console.log('Widget update called.'); 
        }
});
```

});